# Easiest way to transform a float into a large int?

Tags: javascript

The payment processor I'm using only accepts values like '1000' for $10, or '1750' for $17.5.

In my program, I get `17.5` as a number and would like to convert to `1750`. Ditto for all floats.

What's the easiest way to achieve this? I have been solving this problem by transforming the number into a string, removing the dot and transforming it back to a number but it is failing at some cases.

Comment: With the warning that "money math" with floating point is generally a bad idea, you can multiply the values by 100 and then truncate with `Math.floor()` (or `Math.round()`, whichever works better for you).

Comment: do you have some examples? why not calculate with integers?

Answer (score 4):

1. Multiply by 100 ( 100 cents in 1 dollar )
2. [`Math.trunc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) to remove trailing decimals

```js
function toCents(n) {
  var c = n * 100;
  return Math.trunc(c);
}

console.log(toCents(17.5));       // 1750
console.log(toCents(17.50));      // 1750
console.log(toCents(120.95));     // 12095
console.log(toCents(1.95));       // 195
```